# SearchDisplayController is not working for custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have implemented this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/ but don't know why its not working for my custom cell. I removed custom cell and used the UITableView default cell and it worked for that.

when i starts writing in SearchBar, table view becomes white and no data is there. Any suggestions how to overcome this problem. I am configuring my project for iOS 6 & 7 not for iOS 8.

thanks.

Comment: r u given the cell class name

Comment: appcoda is already given the source project with the example, take a look of it.

Comment: i have seen the appCoda sample project and after seeing that i created a new test project but it wont work..

Comment: yeah i have given the name of a class to custom cell..

Answer (score 0):

So finally, i made it.

if any one suffers from the same problem in iOS 6 or 7 then make a separate .xib file and configure your cell.. then register your nib file with following code.

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"your_nibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"your_nibIdentifier"];
```

the above link of appCoda tutorial works fine for iOS 8.